# /usr/lib/ld cannot open output file unit_test: is a directory

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, clion

I have a problem while programming an Asteroid-like videogame in C++ for an exam I will have in a few days. I'm using a JetBrains CLion 1.3 IDE. When I try to implement a unit test with GoogleTest framework (version 1.7.0), I get this error by the compiler:

```
[ 40%] Built target core
[ 80%] Built target asteroids
[ 85%] Built target gtest
[ 87%] Linking CXX executable unit_test
/usr/bin/ld: impossibile aprire il file di output unit_test: È una directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/unit_test.dir/build.make:95: set di istruzioni per l'obiettivo "unit_test" non riuscito
make[2]: *** [unit_test] Errore 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:104: set di istruzioni per l'obiettivo "CMakeFiles/unit_test.dir/all" non riuscito
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/unit_test.dir/all] Errore 2
make[1]: *** Attesa per i processi non terminati....
[ 91%] Built target gtest_main
Makefile:127: set di istruzioni per l'obiettivo "all" non riuscito
make: *** [all] Errore 2
```

What I want to ask is about the line:

`/usr/bin/ld: impossibile aprire il file di output unit_test: È una directory`

translated from italian, it means (literally):

`/usr/bin/ld: cannot open output file unit_test: Is a directory`

What's wrong with my code? I suppose it's a CMakeLists.txt problem, so here are my CMakeLists.txt files (one from the main directory, the other from the "test subdirectory"):

**Main Directory CMakeLists.txt** (part regarding the googletest build):

```
add_subdirectory(test)

add_executable(unit_test main.cpp)
add_library(core ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(unit_test core)
```

**Test Directory CMakeLists.txt** (full):

```
add_subdirectory(googletest)
set(gtest_SOURCE_DIR, googletest)
include_directories(${gtest_SOURCE_DIR}/include
        ${gtest_SOURCE_DIR})

set(SOURCE_FILE runAllTests runAllTests.cpp AsteroidFixture.cpp)
add_executable(runAllTests ${SOURCE_FILE})
target_link_libraries(runAllTests gtest gtest_main core)
```

I created the AsteroidFixture.cpp file as a first try for the main gtest functions, but it's essentially an empty file.

Comment: Do you have collision between an executable named 'unit_test' and a subdirectory in the test area named 'unit_test'?  The output error seems to indicate that the executable cannot be create because there is already a directory of that name

Comment: @Matthew Fisher Before creating the "test" folder, I created the "unit_test" folder. Then, I used the Refractor to erase it completely. Do this matter?

Comment: @FedericoMàlato did you clear the CMake cache afterwards? Can be done by deleting CMakeCache.txt

Comment: If the directory is erases then no it will not matters.  @FedericoMàlato may be correct with his idea about the cmake cache.

Comment: I have just tried to do what you both suggested: it seems to work, but now I have another problem: I built another library before GoogleTest (in particular it was SFML 2.3.2) and now the compiler end with a lot of "undefined reference to... <all SFML functions> ". What can I do now?

Comment: @MatthewFisher in my case the error arised in a Qt project, following your tip I changed the TARGET properpty in the pro file which was colliding with the directory name and it worked!